# Copy Specific Sheet from Drive Folder and Paste Data into Active Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 10 to 15 Files in the Drive Folder All files have more than 1 Google sheets in it with some sort of Conditional Formatting.

I want to copy the Specific Sheet Named "MasterSheet" from each File and Combine the data into the Active Sheet where from script is bieng run.

Copied data should keep conditional formatting cell color. I will appreciate the help. Thanks

```
function myFunction() 
{
  var myFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FolderID");
  var spreadSheets = myFolder.getFilesByType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");
  var ActiveSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(Sheet1);
  while(spreadSheets.hasNext()) 
  {
    var sheet = spreadSheets.next();
    var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet.getId());
    for(var y in spreadSheet.getSheets()) 
    {
      spreadSheet.getSheets()[y].copyTo(ActiveSpreadSheet); 
     }
  }      
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE to check if there's a sheet called that way:

```
function copywithLog() 
{
  var destinsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var myFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("16CxTO70ipcUt8U_beokid3vFOOLGTnPh");
  var spreadSheets = myFolder.getFilesByType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");
  var activeSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var i = 1
  while(spreadSheets.hasNext()) 
  {

    var sheet = spreadSheets.next();
    var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet.getId());
    var sheets = spreadSheet.getSheets()
    var filtered = sheets.filter(n => ["DATA"].lastIndexOf(n.getSheetName()) == 0)
    if (filtered.length==1){
    var newsheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('DATA').copyTo(destinsheet)
    newsheet.getDataRange().copyTo(activeSpreadSheet.getRange(activeSpreadSheet.getLastRow()+2,1))
    destinsheet.deleteSheet(newsheet)
    Logger.log("Process successfully finished with the workbook named '"+spreadSheet.getName()+"'")}
    else Logger.log("The worbook named '"+spreadSheet.getName()+ "' does not have a sheet called DATA")
    

  }      
}
```

It returns something like this:

[image]

UPDATE:

```
function copyinsamesheet() 
{
  var destinsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var myFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FolderID");
  var spreadSheets = myFolder.getFilesByType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");
  var activeSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var i = 1
  while(spreadSheets.hasNext()) 
  {
    var sheet = spreadSheets.next();
    var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet.getId());
    var newsheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('MasterSheet').copyTo(destinsheet)
    newsheet.getDataRange().copyTo(activeSpreadSheet.getRange(activeSpreadSheet.getLastRow()+2,1))
    destinsheet.deleteSheet(newsheet)
    

  }      
}
```

If it has always the same name, you can try with this:

```
function copyMasterSheets() 
{
  var destinsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var myFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FolderID");
  var spreadSheets = myFolder.getFilesByType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");
  var ActiveSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(Sheet1);
  var i = 1
  while(spreadSheets.hasNext()) 
  {

    var sheet = spreadSheets.next();
    var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet.getId());
    spreadSheet.getSheetByName('MasterSheet').copyTo(destinsheet).setName('MasterSheet '+i)
    i++

  }      
}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer. I think i did mistake in explaining I want to combine all the Copied Sheet into Single Sheet. but the script is creating separate sheets.

Comment: Try new option!

Comment: Thank you there is one error i am getting is attached above @Martín

Comment: Are you sure each file in that folder has a sheet named DATA??

Comment: sorry for being late and Yes i am damn sure about that.

Comment: I have tested again. Let's do something, I added an update that will check that and should give you a log without  throwing an error. Try it and let me know

Comment: thank you @Martín Is it possible to Paste data as values but keep the cell color not conditional formatting.

Answer (score 1):

An addendum to the answer by @Martin.
This takes the data on the various "Master Sheets" and copies it to a single sheet.

The range of data on each sheet is established dynamically, and is stacked down the page.

---

```
function copyMasters(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var target = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  
  // idetify the starting row
  var activeStartRow = 1

  // get an array of all the sheets with names like "MasterSheet"
  var sheetList = new Array
  var sheets = ss.getSheets()
  //var sourcesheet = ss.getSheets().find(sheet => sheet.getName().includes("MasterSheet"))
  var mastersheets = sheets.filter(sheet => sheet.getName().includes("MasterSheet"))
  
  //loop through the Master sheets
  for (var i=0;i<mastersheets.length;i++){

    var mastername = mastersheets[i].getName()
    var master = ss.getSheetByName(mastername)
    var masterLC = master.getLastColumn()
    var masterLR = master.getLastRow()

    // calculate the start row for the target sheet
    if (activeStartRow==1){
        var startRow =1        
    }else{
      var startRow=startRow+masterLR
    }
    activeStartRow = 0

    var rangeToCopy = master.getRange(1, 1, masterLR,masterLC)
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: range to copy:"+rangeToCopy.getA1Notation())
    var targetRange = target.getRange(startRow, 1, masterLR,masterLC)
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: target range:"+targetRange.getA1Notation())

    rangeToCopy.copyTo(targetRange)
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: copied the data for "+mastername)
  }
}
```

---

**SAMPLE**

[image: snapshot]

Comment: thanks for posting an answer but i am unable to understand how to know that which folder and its sheets i want to load? @Tedinoz

Comment: This is NOT another version of Martin's script. You accepted the answer by @Martin - that script gets the data from the sheets in the given Drive folder, copies the relevant sheets named "Master Sheet" into your spreadsheet and renames them "MasterSheet1", "MasterSheet2", etc. _This_ script is run AFTER Martin's script (add the function to your Project Editor). _This script_ will identify any sheets in your spreadsheet with a name like "MasterSheet1", "MasterSheet2", etc and will copy the contents (plus formatting) of those sheets into the default sheet.